# Traduction de « clueless / cluelessness »

Tags: traduction, anglais, registre-familier

[*Clueless*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/clueless) (informal, adj.) / [*cluelessness*](http://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/cluelessness) (n). Il s'agit en partie de *ne rien connaître* ([*Collins*](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english-french/clueless)), c'est parfois péjoratif et intense ([*Larousse*](http://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/anglais-francais/clueless/570690)), et on a cette idée de *ne pas avoir d'indice*, d'être (pris au) dépourvu, de naïveté etc. On peut imaginer en contexte :

> You can't make him/her the new [title], (s)he's clueless. And such cluelessness casts a shadow on the [office/business].

On connaît l'adjectif *ignorant* et le nom *ignorance* dans les deux langues. Comment rendrait-on l'adjectif *clueless* (plus usuellement et succinctement *que personne qui n'y connaît rien*) et l'état de *cluelessness* qui s'y rattache ?

Comment: Question difficile. Je ne vois pas de traduction immédiate. [WordReference propose](http://www.wordreference.com/enfr/clueless) « nul » qui ne me semble pas convenir (la différence de registre me paraît trop importante) et « incapable » qui, lui, pourrait peut-être convenir à ce type de contexte. Avec par conséquent « incapacité » pour « _cluelessness_ ». Ceci n'est cependant pas une proposition générique et dépend du contexte. Quant à trouver une autre solution, c'est moi qui suis pour l'instant _clueless_ (ma proposition ici : « n'avoir aucune idée »).

Comment: `incompétent(e)/incompétence` semble aller. On parle ici d'un rapport à un travail, où des compétences sont requises... Maintenant, si on parle d'un travail créatif, où on a besoin d'avoir des idées, on pourrait garder `incompétent(e)` au départ, et faire une périphrase pour `cluelessness`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dans un contexte professionnel, par rapport à l'exemple donné, je proposerais:

- Il n'est pas assez avisé, averti, expérimenté ;
- Il manque de pratique, d'expérience;
- Il est trop novice, bleu, inexpérimenté.

Et

- Une telle inexpérience, naïveté, candeur ;
- Un tel manque de maturité, maîtrise, métier, savoir-faire.

À combiner *ad libitum*...

Comment: Merci ! Plusieurs choix intéressants. Bleu, j'ai du vérifier l'origine, c'est bien intéressant ! Pense-t-on que le contexte de l'exemple est ce qui motive les choix ici, plus que le sens comme tel du mot ?

Comment: Je le pense. Il est fait allusion à la nomination de la personne et à la réputation du service, d'où mon sentiment que l'on doit retenir un mot spécifique à un contexte professionnel. Mettez-vos dans le "bain" de la situation...

Answer (score 1):

Je vois et emplois « clueless » presque uniquement dans les échanges familiers et surtout comme un constat, insultant oui, mais quand même  un peu plus délicate/diplomatique (et beaucoup plus familier) qu’ ‘ignorant/incompétent’ pour expliquer (et même parfois excuser) les actes/paroles de quelqu'un dans un domaine particulier (par exemple, ‘He’s not purposely being impolite/offensive/racist/sexist, he’s just clueless [about such things]’).

D’apres moi, « clueless », sans ajuter « **about everything** », ne veut pas dire que quelqu'un est totalement nul **en tout** ni, comme propose Larousse, que c’est quelqu'un  « [qui ne sait rien **de rien**](http://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/anglais-francais/clueless/570690) »

Donc, dans le contexte de votre exemplaire (assez ‘formal’), je pencherais vers « [inconscient de](http://context2.reverso.net/info.php?q=inconscient+de&langFrom=fr&langTo=en&langTot=fr-en) » qui capte deux notions plus ‘polies’ que j’associe avec « clueless » :

« unaware of » [9 exemplaires] and « oblivious to » [6 exemplaires].

Et puis pour le nom, « [inconscience](http://context2.reverso.net/info.php?q=inconscience&langFrom=fr&langTo=en&langTot=fr-en) » . (Il/elle ne peut pas faire ce job car il/elle [en] est inconscient/e [de ce qu’il en faut pour réussir]. Et une telle inconscience nuirait à la réputation du bureau.)

As is painfully clear, I’m seriously struggling with my French here (not to mention with the content of my answer), so please permit me to add one last thought and suggestion in English:

Personally I think “clueless’/”cluelessness” belong in informal/familiar exchanges, often good-natured, between friends.  Therefore, even my “inconscient de”/”inconscience” are, imho, too formal to use for “clueless/cluelessness.”

In such informal settings, I’d use the informal “[complètement] [paumé(e)](http://context2.reverso.net/info.php?langFrom=fr&langTo=en&q=paum%C3%A9&langTot=fr-en)/[débousselé(e)](http://dictionary.reverso.net/french-english/deboussol%C3%A9)” for “clueless” and for “cluelessness” perhaps a noun that captures the state of being “lost” to go with “paumé/débousselé,” such as “moments d'[égarement](http://dictionary.reverso.net/french-english/egarement)” or "[désorientation](http://dictionary.reverso.net/french-english/desorientation)."

Comment: Thanks! To my ear “innocent/ce” would be a bit too diplomatic to use for “clueless/ness” (except in 'the bedroom’  where it would be PERFECT), BUT your mentioning “innocent” made me think of “poor thing, s/he’s gonna get eaten alive” (NOT in the bedroom sense!), which, imo, goes so well with the notion of “clueless/ness.” So a click or two back from “innocence” there’s a word that I now feel is the best context-neutral choice, at least for the noun; one that you mentioned in your question (AND in an earlier comment to me) & one that Chambaron offered in the rightfully accepted answer: naïveté!

Answer (score 0):

Un complément au sujet d'une expression familière, essentiellement *régionale* (Québec/Canada), originalement empruntée à un ancien sens qu'avait *dessein* (en Normandie : *intelligence, réflexion* ; dit *DHLF/Rey*) et qu'on note au *TLFi* dans le cadre d'un sens plus moderne :

> − ***Sans dessein***. Sans intention arrêtée, sans but défini. *Agir
>   sans dessein. Il ne va pas là sans dessein* (Ac.1798-1932).
>  ♦
>   *Emploi subst.* ou *adj.*, *vx* ou *région.* (Canada). *Le plus sans dessein, le plus ignorant du village* (F. Leclerc, *Le Fou de l'Île*,
>   Montréal, éd. Fides, 1962, 2<sup>e</sup>éd., p. 146).
>
> [ *Trésor de la langue française informatisé*, TLFi : [dessein](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/dessein) ]

À utiliser avec *c'est un(e)/il(elle) est trop* en particulier ; usuel mais assurément plus marqué qu'une référence à la naïveté etc.. La construction avec *sans* s'apparente davantage à la forme anglaise du mot ; il y a aussi une proximité de sens entre *ne pas avoir d'indice* et le sens moderne du dessein soit le [but](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/but) (sans but, sans boussole etc.). Par ailleurs j'ai noté un [exemple](http://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2alpha/alpha-fra.html?lang=fra&i=1&index=alt&srchtxt=CLUELESS%20J%20CROIS%20PAS%20HABILITANT%20ETUDIANTS%20SAVOIR%20FINANCIER) particulier au Canada où on n'a pas traduit.

Quant à l'état, j'opterais, avec la même vigueur, pour la [*bêtise*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/b%C3%AAtise) dans le sens de la métonymie sur les manifestations extérieures de cette absence de *dessein*. Et ça qualifie incidemment aussi la nomination de la personne en soi dans le contexte de l'exemple. D'autre part, on aime bien l'[*incurie*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/incurie), mais ce n'est pas particulièrement usuel et ça implique une indifférence presque active plutôt qu'un manque de savoir faire. Il ne s'agit pas de régionalismes ici ; ces termes sont aussi probablement moins nuancés que ce qu'on recherche, quoiqu'utiles.